# Power Query Conditional Running Total with If Statement

Tags: excel, powerquery

After a week of research and many attempts, I kindly ask for help, please.

I have got the code works so close yet it's causing missed calculations.

I am trying to perform grouped running total with an if statement that evaluates if the next sum will result in a value greater than the value calculated with the previous total, and if does, add those calculations and then continue evaluating the next steps...

**Here is my Code**

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTable"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, 
Int64.Type),
CorrectTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"Index", 
Int64.Type}, {"Filter", type text}, {"Volume", type number}}),

each List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(CorrectTypes, (Q) =>  Q[Filter] = 
[Filter] and Q[Index] <= [Index])[Volume]), type number),

Runing = Table.Group(CorrectTypes,"Filter",{"A", each let 
  A = Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"i")
  in Table.AddColumn(A,"R", each 
    List.Accumulate(Table.SelectRows(A, (a)=> a[i]<=[i])[Volume], 
[Running=0, Verifier = 1], 
// Here the challenge begins 
     (s,l)=> [Running = if s[Running]+l > 
(Number.RoundUp(s[Running]+[Volume]/[Cube])*[Cube]) then 
((Number.RoundUp(s[Running]/[Cube])*[Cube])-s[Running])+s[Running]+ 
[Volume] else s[Running]+l  , Verifier =Number.From(s[Running]+l 
<=Number.RoundUp(s[Running]/[Cube])*[Cube] )]  ))
}),
ExpandedR = Table.ExpandRecordColumn( 
Table.ExpandTableColumn(Runing, "A", {"Volume","Cube","i", "R"}), 
"R", {"Running", "Verifier"})
in
ExpandedR
```

To Explain the question best here is the Excel File demonstrating desired calculation.

[Query Results And Desire Outcome through Excel Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HYnc.png)

What is a super easy step in excel formulas, So far very challenging in the M language?

I have used many great examples from the web yet none answer the complexity of my query.

The data self contains only 3 columns:

**Filter** -to do the grouping,
**Volume** - to sum up,
**cube** - to use for exception calculations,

Here are the links to resources I have used through my tryouts

[Conditional running total in Power Query](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKJbHImHvBY)

[[POWER QUERY] Grouped Running Totals with a maximum condition and a verifier](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/power-query-grouped-running-totals-with-a-maximum-condition-and-a-verifier.1186541/)

[Running Total Power Query with Treshold](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/a7xeh9/conditional_running_total_in_power_query/)

[Power Query All Over Running Totals](https://www.sumproduct.com/blog/article/power-query-blogs/power-query-all-over-running-totals)

[Power Query Running Total with Grouping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFQBMJ6JyCQ)

[Link to Solussion](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Power-Query-Conditional-Running-Total-with-If-Statement-Advanced/m-p/2651658#M81274)

Here are Two Codes which resolve my problem thanks to chaps on PowerQueryForum... link below

**The Function**

```
 fxCalc
 (A)=>
 let
    RunningTotal = Table.AddColumn(
                        A, 
                        "Running Total", 
                        each 
                            if [Volume] < 
                                    
(Number.RoundUp(List.Sum(List.InsertRange(List.FirstN(A[Volume], 
[Index]),0,{0})) / [Cube], 0) * [Cube]) 
                                    - 
List.Sum(List.InsertRange(List.FirstN(A[Volume],[Index]),0,{0})) 
                            then @RunningTotal[Running Total] 
{[Index]-1} + [Volume] 
                            else List.Sum(List.FirstN(A[Volume], 
[Index]+1)) 
                                    + 
 
((Number.RoundUp(List.Sum(List.InsertRange(List.FirstN(A[Volume], 
[Index]),0,{0})) / [Cube], 0) * [Cube])
                                    - 
 List.Sum(List.InsertRange(List.FirstN(A[Volume],[Index]),0, 
  {0})))
                    ),
    CubeFill = Table.AddColumn(
                    RunningTotal, 
                    "Cube Fill", 
                    each [Running Total]/[Cube]
                ),
    PositionCount = Table.AddColumn(
                        CubeFill, 
                        "Position Count", 
                        each Number.RoundUp([Cube Fill],0)
                    ),
    RemainingSpace = Table.AddColumn(
                        PositionCount, 
                        "Remaining Space", 
                        each [Position Count] * [Cube] - [Running 
 Total]
                    )
 in
    RemainingSpace
```

**Main Query**

```
let
Source = 
Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText
("i45Wc 
lTSUTLQMzACU4amSrE6cDFTLGLmRKqzRBZzwmKHExa9TljscMYpZmKKRR3C3lgA", 
BinaryEncoding.Base64)
, Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type 
nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table 
[Filter = _t, Volume = _t, Cube = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Filter", 
type text}, {"Volume", type number}, {"Cube", type number}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Filter"}, 
{{"Group", each fxCalc(Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index",0,1))}}),
Combine = Table.Combine(#"Grouped Rows"[Group])
in
Combine
```

**Option 2**

```
let
Source = 



Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress
(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTLQMzACU4amQMpQKVYHLm6KEDdCFjdHiBvjUG+
CLG6JEDcFizth2GuGLI5kjjmyOJK9FmBxZwxxSyRxEyRzDA2QNSA5yBDo41gA", 
BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type 
nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Filter 
= _t, Volume = _t, Cube = _t, Index = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Filter", 
type text}, {"Volume", type number}, {"Cube", type number}, 
{"Index", type text}}),
Aggregate = List.Accumulate(Table.ToRecords(#"Changed Type"), {}, 
(a,n)=> a & {
Record.AddField(Record.AddField(n, "CubeFill", n[Volume] + (if 
List.IsEmpty(a) or List.Last(a)[CubeFill] + n[Volume] > n[Cube] or 
List.Last(a)[Filter] <> n[Filter] then 0 else List.Last(a) 
[CubeFill])),
"PositionCount", if List.IsEmpty(a) or List.Last(a)[Filter] <> 
n[Filter] then 1 else if List.Last(a)[CubeFill] + n[Volume] > 
n[Cube] then List.Last(a) 
[PositionCount]+Number.RoundUp(n[Volume]/n[Cube], 0)  else 
List.Last(a)[PositionCount])}),
Output = Table.FromRecords(Aggregate)
in
Output
```

Comment: It is extremely hard to tell what you want.  Paragraph2 describes the columns as Filter for Running total_Drop_Level, Volume and Cube Per Position then suddenly we have cube per possession in Paragraph 3. To make this easier to help you, Please provide some sample input data, sample output data, and enough annotations to understand how you get from input to output

Comment: To Explain better  I have added excel formula with what I am trying to achieve in M language.

Comment: You have added excel formula screenshot without including any of the row / column titles on the side so we still can't tell what is going on.

Comment: just corrected, sorry

Comment: For Those who need it as much as I did, here I the link to the solution   https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Power-Query-Conditional-Running-Total-with-If-Statement-Advanced/m-p/2651658#M81274